# PHP Round to 4 Decimal places not working?

Tags: php

gives 3 digit number in below operation. Must be 4 decimals and numeric format.

```
$num = 500948.88880000;
$num2 = 10.3338;
return round($num - $num2, 4);
// 500938.555
```

must be : **500938.5550** but numeric format. ( No String )

```
{
    "data": {
        "balance": 500938.5550,
        "currency": "TRY"
    },
    "status": {
        "code": "0",
        "message": "Success",
        "datetime": "2022-08-29T08:28:02+00:00"
    }
}
```

Comment: `round()` won't display extra 0's at the end because its intention is to round the number. you can use `number_format()` interchangeably in your case I believe. Replacing `return round($num - $num2, 4);` with `return number_format($num - $num2, 4);` should give you the result your looking for

Comment: yes it gives number_format results but string

Comment: Do you have a reason you need it to be in a number format? PHP is a typeless language so it can usually figure it out for you.

Comment: This is a common question, and a non-problem. `123.4560` is exactly equivalent to `123.456`. Trailing zeros have no significance, are not stored and no mechanism for storing them in numeric format exists. `number_format()` will return the presentation you want as a string. Explain exactly **why** you need this. I'd bet that there's no good reason.

Comment: @JDawwgy@Tangentially
they want them in the form of numbers in the json output

Comment: @ege There's absolutely no need to include trailing zeros in a JSON number.

Answer (score 1):

You can use number_format to format the output

```
$num = 500948.88880000;
$num2 = 10.3338;

$round = round($num - $num2, 4);
echo number_format($round, 4, ".", "");
```

How this work:

```
   number_format(
        float $num,
        int $decimals = 0,
        ?string $decimal_separator = ".",
        ?string $thousands_separator = ","
    ): string
```

**$num:** The number being formatted.

**$decimals:**  Sets the number of decimal digits. If 0, the decimal_separator is omitted from the return value.

**$decimal_separator:** Sets the separator for the decimal point.

**$thousands_separator:** Sets the thousands separator.

Reference: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php

Comment: return 500938.555 and string. Must be 4 decimals and numeric format.

Comment: But with number_format, will return 4 decimals and numeric format